# Is CC-BY-SA-4.0 appropriate for this use case?

Tags: license-recommendation, creative-commons

The use case is for an image I made from scratch using gimp, I was thinking about using CC-BY-SA-4.0 but I am not sure if it is the right license for this. The image you print out, cut and then you tape it or glue it to a physical tool that will provide a cheat sheet so you do not have to do the precise math (in mm). It basically goes over the information that is normally there and can give you more precise details than what is already labeled on the tool (working on it still).

Right now there is only one version and each version can give the same level of detail in mm as the tool normally does. I plan on making it so you can have a small mm on a tool labeled for a larger one or maybe a universal one.

The main thing is you can get the exact mm quicker than without it. And it allows you to quickly identify how precise in mm it is without doing the math and you do not need to know how to read the tool to get the information with it.

Basically I want a GPL 2 license but for stuff like this where it is a image cause I believe GPL 2 is more for software and code and not images, documentation.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [how do I ask for a license recommendation?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/463/458)  You've told us a fair bit about how you think people will use your work, but nothing about how you feel about *other* possible uses.  If I want to modify for use with hacksaws, are you OK with that? If I want to include a copy of your sheet with each hacksaw I sell, how about that?  If I want to use it as supplementary material in my youtube series on d-i-y, how about that?  If you can in very general terms tell us what other uses of your work should be allowed, that'd help!

Comment: I definitely would like people to be able to modify it for other tools or other uses cause I only plan on making it for one type of tool which is the only tool I have that I think could use this. I want it to be pretty open but not too open like mit but open enough that I get credit for it. But still allows freedom. Basically I believe people should be able to modify, distribute and use it commercially but not sell the file I think selling the print out would be fine. I don't want to be held liable for anything. I would like the license to not change and include a source to the originally imag

Comment: Basically I want a gpl 2 license but for stuff like this where it is a image cause I believe gpl 2 is more for software and code and not images, documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming by your statement that you want "a GPL 2 license but for stuff like this where it is a image" that your primary concern is for a copyleft license, then yes, CC-BY-SA is probably the right answer: it is a copyleft license designed for "non-code stuff", and the most common copyleft license used for that purpose, thus helping to reduce license proliferation.